# Latest contribution token pulling data from previous contributions

Tags: tokens

I have a Civi rule that sends a notification email to staff for donations over $1,000.  I include the tokens "latest contribution amount", "latest contribution date", and "latest contribution financial type".  It seemed to be working fine, but recently while the rule is working, the token data is pulling from the 2nd latest contribution?  How can I get the data from the latest contribution?

Comment: I don't find this token. Does it come from an extension (I haven't found it in Fuzion tokens extension) or a data processor token output?

Comment: @GuillaumeSorel I believe it's part of Fuzion tokens?

Comment: I would try delaying the CiviRules Action by a minute, just to see if perhaps the contribution has not been fully saved yet at the moment the email is sent.